# DynamoDB: Insert a new Row with unique GSI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using DynamoDBMapper to insert a new object to my table.
Table structure:

```
key: hash_key
attribute1: global sec index
other attributes
```

Now i want the value of attribute1 to be unique in the table. How to do that?

Already tried:

```
a. map.put("attribute1", new ExpectedAttributeValue(false));
b. map.put("atrribute1", new ExpectedAttributeValue().withExists(false));
```

I am using `mapper.save()` with default SaveBehaviour.

Answer (score 0):

you basically cannot do that with a GSI.
The index does not say nothing about uniqueness. It just indexes the table for faster lookup based on that attribute

also see:
[DynamoDB key uniqueness across primary and global secondary index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350256/dynamodb-key-uniqueness-across-primary-and-global-secondary-index)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to enforce uniqueness on an attribute that's not the primary key, I would recommend taking a look at this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920884/is-there-a-way-to-enforce-unique-constraint-on-a-property-field-other-than-the)